Capture - Java Heap Dump Consumption Data
I am experiencing an OutOfMemoryError in my Java application and do not know how to resolve it. I enabled memory saving mode but it did not help the problem.
Do I have an option to capture one week's heap consumption metrics? I am using VisualVM (V2.1.9).

Have you read the documentation for VisualVM? It details how to analyze a heap dump.
